# How do I remove instances that have ever had a specific value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently trying to generate information which identifies people who were not present on a specific date. I'm using MySQL Workbench.

I have the following tables (summarised for brevity):

```
Employee - Emp_ID, Emp_StartDate
Job - Job_ID, Emp_ID
```

I want to get a list of employees and their start dates which excludes employees who were working on a specific job.

The data looks kind of like this:

```
Job_ID - Emp_ID 
Job_AA - Emp_XX 
Job_BB - Emp_XX
Job_BB - Emp_YY
Job_CC - Emp_YY
Job_AA - Emp_ZZ
Job_BB - Emp_YY
```

I want to get information only for employees who did not work on Job_AA, regardless of whether or not they also worked on other jobs.

I'm very much a beginner and my basic starting point is this:

```
SELECT Emp_ID, Emp_StartDate
FROM Employee 
JOIN Job USING (Emp_ID)
WHERE Job_ID != "Job_AA";
```

The issue I run into is that, for example, Emp_XX will still show up as having worked on Job_BB, which I do not want - Emp_XX needs to not appear on the generated list. I feel like this requires a subquery but I cannot figure out what needs to go in there.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT e.Emp_ID, e.Emp_StartDate
FROM Employee e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM Job
  WHERE Emp_ID = e.Emp_ID AND Job_ID = 'Job_AA'
)
```

Or with join and GROUP BY employee:

```
SELECT e.Emp_ID, e.Emp_StartDate
FROM Employee e INNER JOIN Job j
ON j.Emp_ID = e.Emp_ID
GROUP BY e.Emp_ID, e.Emp_StartDate
HAVING SUM(j.Job_ID = 'Job_AA') = 0
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried the first one and it generated no items, and the second one still ran into the problem of Emp_XX appearing when I want to exclude them - any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have your actual data. My code is very simple and it works: if an empi_id exists in the table job with Job_ID = 'Job_AA' then that emp_id is not in the results. All the other emp_ids are returned.

Comment: My b - you are right! The first option worked (I had broken it because I have to select multiple Job_IDs and typo'd).  Thank you so much!